# MLCP import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error?

Tags: hadoop, marklogic, mlcp

```
> 17/12/01 15:11:19 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type is set
> to MIXED.  The format of the  inserted documents will be de ication
> configured on MarkLogic Server. java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:70)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.<init>(JobContextImpl.java:72)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:144)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:131)
>         at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJob.<init>(LocalJob.java:37)
>         at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJob.getInstance(LocalJob.java:58)
>         at com.marklogic.contentpump.Command$1.createJob(Command.java:353)
>         at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:226)
>         at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74) Caused
> by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:129)
>         ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative(Native
> Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:49)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:39)
```

Command used -

```
mlcp.bat import -mode local -host xyz.com -port 8013 -username abc -password abc@123 -input_file_path C:\Users\abc\Documents\MarkLogic\MLCP_Data\gs\import
```

Comment: Please provide full stack trace as text rather than image. Make sure you copy the stack trace till the end. The tail usually contains the vital details..

Comment: @grtjn done. please check now

Comment: This ticket seems similar: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6212. It suggests it is a config error. MLCP should be packaged and tested properly, so it sounds more like something was off with it. What version were you using, and can you try latest?

Comment: @grtjn - I used mlcp v9 and host MarkLogic cluster is v8